# Excel: PivotTable - Need to divide running total field by Grand Total of a count field

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I feel like I have to be making this more complicated than it needs to be...

I have a pivot table that is arranged by date. I have one field whose values are the sum of students registered for a class. The values are shown as a running total by date. My other field is the count of students enrolled in the school.

I want to divide the running total of students registered in the class for each day by the grand total of students enrolled in the school. My ultimate goal is to have a running percentage of students registered for the class.

I cannot seem to find a way to do this calculation within the pivot table. More dates are added each day, so the calculations need to be dynamic. If I try to change my registered for class field to be a % of Grand Total, it wants to pull the grand total of that same column, rather than the grand total of the students enrolled in the school. If I try to change my registered for class field to be a "% of..", the only option Excel gives me is for the base field is the date.

Any suggestions?

Comment: May well require Power Pivot, though it's difficult to be certain without knowing the specifics. Suggest you post a very small sample dataset together with expected results.

Answer (score 1):

*This solves the issue:*

**N.B. :** key of the solution is "*I want to divide the running total of students registered in the class for each day by the grand total of students enrolled*".

[image]

**How it works:**

- **Method 1** is based on simple formula in cell I2:

  `=H2*100/$H$16`
- Fill it down.
- Apply Custom Cell Format `0.00 "%"`

---

- **Method 2** is based on Pivot Table.
- Select Source data `F1:H15` & insert a Pivot table.
- Put Date field in Rows, Registered & Enrolled in Values.
- Put the Enrolled field twice in Values.
- Rename the PT column headings.
- Select Grand Total in Column N, then Right Click.
- Hit Show Value as, then % of Grand Total.

**N.B.**

- *You may avoid Inserting Enrolled column twice in the Pivot table*.
- The Class name column can be included in source data to make the PT
  results more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

It's best show us a sample for better analysis.

Please check the creating a new caculated field is helpful.

You can select the pivot table > PivotTable Analyze > Fields, Iterms and Sets > Caculated Fields.

Create a new field, such as "% of Registrations" to divide the number of attendees by the number of registrants. And drag this field under Values area.

[image]